# How do I insert an audio into another audio file at a particular time using python?

Tags: python, audio, editing, pydub

I want to merge two audio files but want some **interval between** them and end result should be a .wav file, How do I do that?
I don't want to overlay the sounds...

Comment: If you had any code so far, it would avoid others doing the heavy lifting

Comment: Use an silent file for the interval